# Seaborn heatmap Python csv file

Tags: python, csv, heatmap, seaborn

I'm trying to do a heatmap using seaborn.

I have a csv file. It is how 3 different things correlate together. All my different lines and columns have a name.

I get this error :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/b/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/pandas/core/nanops.py in _ensure_numeric(x)
767         try:
--> 768             x = float(x)
769         except Exception:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'abc'
```

That's my code :

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/b/Desktop/ex.csv")

sns.lmplot(x='names', y='names', data=df)
```

I tried to delete the names but them it use my first column and first row as the names.

Thanks

[image: image from the csv]

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/1422451)

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the "names". Works well now!